# Linux: How to add $ symbol inside alias?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, alias, csh

Well I use 'csh' shell. I have a `sed` command as below to fetch the data from String1 to next emptyNewLine.

```
sed -n '/startString/,/^$/p' myLog.log  # ==> works fine
```

But when I am using the above `sed` command inside 'alias' i am getting the below error:

```
<48 sne-70 [sunil_c85see] :/home1/sunil_c85see>alias check "sed -n '/startString/,/^$/p' myLog.log"
**Illegal variable name.**
```

Any suggestion how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
alias check "sed -n '/startString/,/^"\$"/p' myLog.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

only a single inverted quotation is required for '%'

```
SELECT salesman_id,name,city,'%',commission*100 FROM salesman;
```

Answer (score -1):

You get an error because you have the wrong syntax for creating aliases, instead try

```
alias check="sed -n '/startString/,/^$/p' myLog.log"
```

Note the `=` between the alias name and the string.

Comment: No ,, i am getting  the same error when i use = also... and below cmd works fine when i remove $ ,,                                                           alias check "sed -n '/startString/,/endString/p' myLog.log"

Comment: @SunilGowda How about escaping the dollar-sign, like in `\$`? Also, can you please edit your question to show the *complete* and *unedited* error message? Copy-paste the actual text from the terminal window into your question, together with the command.